# Quotation marks inside a list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I want to place quotations for every element in a list. I am trying this

```
col = Table["\"" i "\"", {i, 0, 5}];
```

and I am getting

```
{0, ("\"")^2, 2 ("\"")^2, 3 ("\"")^2, 4 ("\"")^2, 5 ("\"")^2}
```

instead of

```
{"0", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
```

How should I correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `ToString` and `StringJoin` : `Table["\"" <> ToString[i] <> "\"", {i, 0, 5}]`. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col = Table["\"" <> ToString@ i <> "\"", {i, 0, 5}]
```

> ```
> {"0","1","2","3","4","5"}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use [`IntegerString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html):

```
IntegerString @ Range[0, 5]
```

> ```
> {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much @kglr

Comment: @GauravMaurya, you are most welcome.